# Как ограничить выборку из БД?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Есть метод который делает запрос в БД

```
public void execute(){
  Connection con;
  Statement st;
  try{
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
   st = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL_QUERY);
   }catch(SQLException e){
          e.getMessage;
      }
  }
```

rs - получает огромное колличество Юзеров (милион +-)
как ограничить выборку данных при каждом обращении? При этом в итоге нужно извлечь всю информацию. И в дальнейшем обрабртать эту информацию не используя Collection?

Comment: прописать в SQL-запросе `LIMIT n` в конце, где n - сколько записей вам необходимо получить

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть такой великолепный метод [Statement.setMaxRows(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows(int)), который ограничивает выборку. Либо же сделать ограничение в SQL при помощи [LIMIT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php).

Если я правильно понял, то вам надо использовать механизм Paggination(не уверен как это правильно по русски, постранично может быть). В рамках JDBC это можно сделать только через SQL. Т.е. должно быть что-то такое:

```
private static final String SQL_SUBLIST = "SELECT * FROM"
    + " (SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id)"
    + " WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN %d AND %d";

public List<Contact> list(int firstrow, int rowcount) {
    String sql = String.format(SQL_SUBLIST, firstrow, firstrow + rowcount);

    // Implement JDBC.
    return contacts;
}
```

Ну и выполнять этот метод пока не обработаете все результаты. так же можете посмотреть [тут(отсюда взят код)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination) или [тут](http://java.avdiel.com/Tutorials/JDBCPaging.html).

Comment: Да метод великолепный. Немного перефразировал вопрос. Нужна вся информация из БД но т.к. ее много нужно обрабатывать по частям. Отсюда и мысль достовать по частям.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте сразу рассмотрим запрос SQL на выборку определённого числа записей:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 5 LIMIT 10
```

Данным запросом мы получим 10 первых записей. Все остальные отпадут. Изменение от обычного SQL-запроса на выборку данных состоит только в параметре "LIMIT". Число, которое идёт за ним, сообщает, какое количество записей мы хотим получить, и в нашем случае - это 10.

Также существует возможность задавать после "LIMIT" два числа:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 5 LIMIT 10, 20
```

Данный SQL-запрос вернёт записи, начиная с 10-го номера включительно в количестве 20-ти штук. То есть первое число означает, с какой записи надо формировать результат выборки, а второе число означает, какое количество записей всего должно быть.

Comment: Второй вариант мне как раз подходит, единственное могу ли я сделать так:     SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 5 LIMIT ?, ? и уже через PrepareStatement задавать параметр.